# Add short content/note to blog posts in WordPress (code or plugin)

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

Legally, I do not have permission to change any content from the Title to the end of the blog post body in a WordPress install.

Sometimes, I love to share a short note and let the blog post visitors know about it.
For example, "this post is #2 of a series posts. for other related please click here or here."
Or, "for more detailed information about this post, click here and read another post."

The note, if there is any!, must be shown on top of the title or below the body.

Any ideas, recommendations are more than welcome.

Answer (score 0):

just hook into the_content filter.
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_content/